# How return data from a GraphQL mutation?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, react-apollo

I have the following redux-form below... How can I get the `console.log` to obtain the user.id from the graphQL mutation result data?

```
const withForm = compose(
  withMySignupMutation,
  reduxForm({
    ...
    onSubmit: async (values, dispatch, {
      mySignup,
    }) => {
      try {
        const result = await mySignup(values);
        console.log('I Need user.id here');
        console.log(result.user.id);
        ...
```

**withMySignupMutation**

```
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const SIGNUP_MUTATION = gql`
mutation (
  $email: String!
  $name: String!
) {
  signup(authProvider: {
    mySignup: {
      email: $email
      name: $name
    }
  }) {
    token
  }
}
`;

export default graphql(
  SIGNUP_MUTATION,
  {
    props: ({ mutate }) => ({
      mySignup: async (variables) => {
        const { data } = await mutate({ variables });
      },
    }),
  }
);
```

Thank you! happy holidays

Comment: Don't know if this is a typo, but you're not logging the result object outside of the quotes.

Comment: @AarohMankad thanks but that was just to show what I'm trying to do. I'll update... Any ideas?

Comment: Does the typedef for the mutation "signup" have a return value.  For example:  signup(authProvider: authProviderInput) : String or something like that.  As an example: addAlley(alley: AlleyInput): Alley this will add the new alley and return the alley back.

Comment: Is the "String or something like that" what is returned?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it should be `result.data.signup.id` but we need to see the resolvers and your schema definition. It depends on what the resolvers are sends back. It should be a User type.

Anyway, **you must ask for the id in your mutation** otherwise it won't get resolved:

```
export const SIGNUP_MUTATION = gql`
mutation (
  $email: String!
  $name: String!
) {
  signup(authProvider: {
    mySignup: {
      email: $email
      name: $name
    }
  }) {
    token
    id ### <===HERE===
  }
}
`
```

And if you have a graphiql access to the server:

- click on the top-right corner the `DOCS` button, then
- click `mutation: Mutation`
- then you should see something like:

`signup(authProvider: AuthProviderNewcomerData!): User`

Then you know you will get a `User` back.